# Strip mail body from html with format preserving with Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

I have a mail content, that may contain html/css. I would like to clean out the text from tags, images, but want to preserve formatting, so it still would be readable enough.

Schema is:

1) Get email from server;

2) Store it in database;

3) Get it by request to a web page through Spring backend

4) Show it sanitized from html/css tags, just plain text, that will contain new lines, whitespaces, some basic formatting.

This code helps me to get rid from html tags, but all the text becomes heavy readable.

```js
var htmlToPlaintext = function(text) {
            return text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
};
```

Any suggestion on how can I achieve desired result?

P.S.: I can pre-process data on java backend, if needed.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "preserve formatting"? That's what the HTML does. It marks up the text, so it can be displayed in a desired format. I'm confused.

Comment: do you want something like this: `console.log(document.body.textContent);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should let the browser do this for you.

check this `getText` function:

```js
function getText(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("div");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
}
var html = document.getElementById("htmlDiv").innerHTML;
alert(getText(html))
```

```html
<div id='htmlDiv'>
  <div>this is first line. <span> another part</span></div>
  <div>this is another line. 
    <p>
      paragraph 1
    </p>
    <p> 
      paragraph 2
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```